# How to get the current and next element of List of list of options in scala

Tags: scala, list, nested-lists, for-comprehension, scala-option

This question might be duplicated, however, I've not come across any question that answers my problem.

So I have a `List[ List[ Option[ Double ] ] ]`

With the following data:

```scala
var tests = List(
  List(Some(313.062468), Some(27.847252)),
  List(Some(301.873641), Some(42.884065)),
  List(Some(332.373186), Some(53.509768))
)
```

I'd like to calculate this equation:

```scala
def findDifference(oldPrice: Option[Double], newPrice: Option[Double]): Option[Double] = {
    return Some(( newPrice.get - oldPrice.get ) / oldPrice.get)
}
```

on the following:

It's doing the calculation on the element of two lists:

`(Some(301.062468) - Some(313.062468)) / Some(313.062468)`

`(Some(332.373186) - Some(301.873641)) / Some(301.873641)`

`(Some(42.884065) - Some(27.847252)) / Some(27.847252)`

`(Some(53.509768) - Some(42.884065)) / Some(42.884065)`

The result should return:
#

```scala
List(
  List(Some(-0.03573991820699504), Some(0.5399747522663995))
  List(Some(0.10103414428290529), Some(0.24777742035415723))
)
```

## My code so far

```scala
def findDifference(oldPrice: Option[Double], newPrice: Option[Double]): Option[Double] = {
    return Some(( newPrice.get - oldPrice.get ) / oldPrice.get)
}

def get_deltas(data: List[List[Option[Double]]]):  List[List[Option[Double]]] = {
  for {
    i <- data
    // So this is where I am stuck. I have the current element i, but I need the same index element in the next list
  } ( findDifference(i,?) }
```

## My output If I print my I in For-comprehension

```js
List(Some(313.062468), Some(27.847252))
List(Some(301.873641), Some(42.884065))
List(Some(332.373186), Some(53.509768))
```

## Where Am I stuck?

I'm stuck in the fact that I don't know how to get the element of the same index in the list 1 from List 2 and List 3 and do the necessary calculation?

Please help me achieve my result output

Comment: What's the point of wrapping your values with `Some`, when you're unwrapping every possible value using `.get` in your `findDifference` method?

Comment: 1 - You can't use a `for` comprehension in that manner if the index of the element is important. 2 - Your code will throw a runtime exception if any of those Options is `None`. (Which is what Options are for.) 3 - I think your data representation is far too complex.

Comment: Ive added some to explain my issue. Its not required ot be inside. I just don't know how to do the calculation. Is there a way of doing it? @jwvh

Comment: @PawełJurczenko There is no point. ive just added it to explain my issue.

Comment: You're so close. See the point where you have `( findDifference(i,?) }`, it should be `( findDifference(i(0),i(1)) }`. My answer below pretty much says the same thing

Comment: @RobertUdah But that doesn't give me the right answer though?

Comment: I think the index values were the wrong way round. should instead be `findDifference(i(1),i(0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to play with this:

```
object OptIdx {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(get_deltas(tests))
  }

  var tests = List(
    List(Some(313.062468), Some(27.847252)),
    List(Some(301.873641), Some(42.884065)),
    List(Some(332.373186), Some(53.509768)))

  def findDifference(oldPrice: Option[Double], newPrice: Option[Double]): Option[Double] = {
    Some((newPrice.get - oldPrice.get) / oldPrice.get)
  }

  def get_deltas(data: List[List[Option[Double]]]): List[List[Option[Double]]] = {
    (for {
      index <- 0 to 1
    } yield {
      (for {
        i <- 0 to data.length - 2
      } yield {
        findDifference(data(i)(index), data(i + 1)(index))
      }).toList
    }).toList
  }

}
```

It prints the numbers you want, but two of them are swapped. I'm sure you can figure it out, though.

Comment: I like how you implemented this, and it works like a charm. But I've tried to look closely why its being swapped. No idea. Any clues?

Comment: @NaseebullahSafi: play with the indices, and with the values. Use numbers that you can verify by hand. Maybe you need to swap the outer loop and the inner, etc

Comment: You deserve this question bro

Answer (score 0):

So your data structure implies that `i` is a list of two options. The values you need are there already so you can call `i(0)` and `i(1)`

I've done a quick and dirty one in the repl:

```
scala> val tests = List(
     |   List(Some(313.062468), Some(27.847252)),
     |   List(Some(301.873641), Some(42.884065)),
     |   List(Some(332.373186), Some(53.509768))
     | )
tests: List[List[Some[Double]]] = List(List(Some(313.062468), Some(27.847252)), List(Some(301.873641), Some(42.884065)), List(Some(332.373186), Some(53.509768)))
```

And here you can see the value of i when I call:

```
scala> for { i <- tests } println(i)
List(Some(313.062468), Some(27.847252))
List(Some(301.873641), Some(42.884065))
List(Some(332.373186), Some(53.509768))
```

So you can call `findDifference` thus:

```
scala> def findDifference(oldPrice: Option[Double], newPrice: Option[Double]): Option[Double] = {
     | Option((oldPrice.get - newPrice.get) /oldPrice.get)
     | }
findDifference: (oldPrice: Option[Double], newPrice: Option[Double])Option[Double]

scala> for { i <- tests } println(findDifference(i(0), i(1)))
Some(0.911048896477747)
Some(0.8579403459740957)
Some(0.8390069648999904)
```

Comment: There are better ways to structure your data. First you could create a case class `Prices(oldPrice: Option[Double], newPrice: Option[Double])` which should make your code easier to follow as you can call params by name, etc. If you are sure to always get a price, then you might not need to use options at all